# Way to change function from include to strict comparison?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

How change this to strict comprassion `==`?

```
if (this.Name) {
   conditions.push(this.filterName);
}

filterName(item) {
   return item.name.toString().includes(this.Name);
}
```

Comment: Strict comparison uses `===`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just compare two names

```
filterName(item) {
   return item.name.toString() === this.Name;
}
```